# Add active class to menu "parent" item if URL has a a /directory/ listing

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to add a CSS class to a a parent item when the URL contains a directory path.

For instance if my url is

`example.com/directory/about.html`

I want to add a CSS class an item in my top navigation if it contains `/directory/` in it.

so in this case, `example.com/directory/overview.html` would get a CSS class "`active-parent`"

which would be `.main-nav li a.active-parent`

(mind you I am already using jquery to check for teh URL and make that page active, but its when its a sub page of a section, the parent is not highlighted)

I thought I could usde the [`:contains() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) but I dont know how to apply it to a URL

Comment: You can do this by javascript. But it should be more efficient to do this on the server side, no ?

Comment: Would love to, however i'm hoping to make a quick temp fix for a site that is hosted on a very old server I have no access to change anything but the filesystem and its locked out.

Comment: Are you checking paths against `location.href`?

Comment: And that `a` is contained within what html? What element should have the 'parent' class?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors can't be used on an url. You must parse the url and check the content be yourself.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/directory/') != -1) {
    // Add a css class to a html element
}
```

You may want to do a more generic way be using the split function :

```
window.location.pathname.split('/').forEach(function(directory) {
    if (directory == 'directory') {
        // Add a css class to a html element
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I f I understand you correctly, you want to filter through a group of urls and then, based on text within the `href`, you want to manipulate data. In that case, use the [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function like so:

```
$("a").filter(function(i) { return $(this).attr("href").indexOf("document") > -1; })
```

This Grabs **ALL** `A` tag elements, filters them using the function inside to determine if the `href` has "document" in it or not. Then simply use the [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to do whatever, like so:

```
$("a")
    .filter(function(i) { return this.href.indexOf("document") > -1; })
    .each(function(i) {
        $(this).parent().addClass("some-class-name");
    });
```

[**## See jsFiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/KEmUQ/)

If you need more understanding, just comment.

Comment: Just a note: `$(this).attr("href").indexOf("document")` is the same as `this.href.indexOf("document")`. The first uses jQuery notation whereas the second uses JavaScript. I'd go with the first just for the fact jQuery will continue to update as standards change. Not likely that .href will ever change, but if it does, jQuery will be there to match a "cross-browser" compatible version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on limited information, I'd suggest:

```
$('a').filter(
    function(){
        return this.href.match(/(\/\w+\/)/);
    }).parent().addClass('parent');
```

This assumes the class is added if the `href` contains *any* directory, not simply a specific directory *named* 'directory'.

References:

- [`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [Regular expressions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).